# How can I align an element with max-height to the vertical center?

Tags: html, css

I have an overlay popup element on my site that I want to be centered both horizontally and vertically. I want the height to grow with the content inside it but to be max 90% of the window height then go over to scrolling.

But the problem is now when I want to add a Close button fixed to the bottom of the popup box. I need the close button to be outside the `overflow:auto` element, but having that content element inside the box and not being the box makes the box not being vertically centered anymore. It works if you set a fixed height. But I want the height to be dynamic and grow with the content, which now is the content box.

I've tried all kind of combinations I can come up with and find online. I've read documentations on about the different styling's behaviors. But can't figure out a solution.

Here is a working example without the close button:

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
body {
  font-family:Roboto;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:12px;
}
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
h1 {
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
h2 {
  padding-bottom:7px;
}
p {
  line-height:1.5em;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.col {
    display: table-cell;
}

.popup-box.active {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inherit;
}

.popup-box>.table,
.popup-box>.table>.row,
.popup-box>.table>.row>.col {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.popup-box>.table>.row>.col {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.popup-box.active .popup-box-content {
  display: block;
  background-color: #272a2e;
  max-height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 7px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 200px;
  padding:20px;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup-box active">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">

          <div class="popup-box-content">

              <h1>Popup Title</h1>

              <p class="ingress">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
                book.
              </p>

              <h2>A random second title</h2>

              <p class="text">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using
                'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the one with the close button, and look at line 72:

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
body {
  font-family:Roboto;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:12px;
}
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
h1 {
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
h2 {
  padding-bottom:7px;
}
p {
  line-height:1.5em;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.col {
    display: table-cell;
}

.popup-box.active {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inherit;
}

.popup-box>.table,
.popup-box>.table>.row,
.popup-box>.table>.row>.col {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.popup-box>.table>.row>.col {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.popup-box.active .popup-box-content-wrap {
  max-height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #272a2e;
  border-radius: 7px;
  position:relative;
}

.popup-box.active .popup-box-content {
  width:calc(100% - 40px);
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: calc(100px - 40px); /* <--- Want this to be 100% instead of 100px */
  text-align: left;
  padding:20px;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.popup-box.active .popup-box-close {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height:160%;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup-box active">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">

        <div class="popup-box-content-wrap">
          <div class="popup-box-content">

              <h1>Popup Title</h1>

              <p class="ingress">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>


            </div>
            
            <div class="popup-box-close">Close</div>
            
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `posotion:fixed;  top:50%; left: 50%` it will solve the problem

Comment: @VikasSingh Of the `.popup-box.active` box? Sorry didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.popup-box.active .popup-box-content-wrap {
  max-height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #272a2e;
  border-top-left-radius: 7px;
  border-top-right-radius: 7px;
  position:relative;
}

.popup-box.active .popup-box-close {
    background-color: #272a2e;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -40px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height:160%;
}
```

Full code:

```
<div id="popup" class="popup-box active">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">

        <div class="popup-box-content-wrap">
          <div class="popup-box-content">

              <h1>Popup Title</h1>

              <p class="ingress">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>


            </div>

            <div class="popup-box-close">Close</div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
    * {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
body {
  font-family:Roboto;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:12px;
}
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
h1 {
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
h2 {
  padding-bottom:7px;
}
p {
  line-height:1.5em;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.col {
    display: table-cell;
}

.popup-box.active {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inherit;
}

.popup-box>.table,
.popup-box>.table>.row,
.popup-box>.table>.row>.col {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.popup-box>.table>.row>.col {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.popup-box.active .popup-box-content-wrap {
  max-height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #272a2e;
  border-top-left-radius: 7px;
  border-top-right-radius: 7px;
  position:relative;
}

.popup-box.active .popup-box-content {
  width:calc(100% - 40px);
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: calc(100px - 40px); /* <--- Want this to be 100% instead of 200px */
  text-align: left;
  padding:20px;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.popup-box.active .popup-box-close {
    background-color: #272a2e;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -40px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height:160%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Yeah but you see, the problem is that I want the line 71 to be `max-height: calc(100% - 40px);`, and it won't work with max-height of 100%.

Comment: I see, you don't want the content to push the close button off the bottom of the window. Let me do some 'sperimenting.

Comment: Try: max-height: calc(100vh - 40px);

Comment: Try adding `margin-bottom: 40px;` to `.popup-box.active .popup-box-content {`

Comment: But that fiddle you sent don't work. Can't see the close button and the height of the whole popup is not 90%, it's 100%.

Comment: That's weird I see the close button on my screen!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very late :P, but was this what you were looking for? I'm using nested divs with `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` as well as a combination of `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: Roboto;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.popup-box.active {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  /* This is the important flex part */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.popup-box-content-wrap {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
  /* This is the important flex part */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.popup-box-content-wrap > div {
  background: black;
}

.popup-box-content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
}

.popup-box-close {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 0 0 7px 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup-box active">
  <div class="popup-box-content-wrap">
    <div class="popup-box-content">
      <h1>Popup Title</h1>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
      <h2>A random second title</h2>
      <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="popup-box-close">Close</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a slightly stripped down version with just the important CSS with more comments. I have also changed the 90% width and height on `.popup-box-content-wrap` to 100% and used padding to create the space between the content box and the browser. This is so the spacing is more consistent across small screen sizes.

```css
/* CSS Resets and global box sizing. */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* This fills the entire window and can be used to apply a transparant background for example. */
.popup-box.active {
  /* Expands to window width and fixed */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* This is the flex part that makes this possible */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.popup-box-content-wrap {
  /* Expands to parents width and height */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* This can be adjusted to change the space between the content box and the edge of the window on small screens */
  padding: 20px;
  /* This width can be adjusted to meet your needs */
  max-width: 400px;
  /* This is the flex part that makes this possible */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.popup-box-content {
  /* Applies the scroll */
  overflow: auto;
}

/* This is purely for visualisation purposes. This selects the popup-box-content and the popup-box-close divs. */
.popup-box-content-wrap > div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup-box active">
  <div class="popup-box-content-wrap">
    <div class="popup-box-content">
      <h1>Popup Title</h1>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
      <h2>A random second title</h2>
      <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="popup-box-close">Close</div>
  </div>
</div>
```